# Best way to iterate over JSON array with variable keys with jq/bash

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I have a JSON-file like the one below:

```
{
    "Results": [
        {
            "Severity": "LOW",
            "InstalledVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2",
            "FixedVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2.1"
        },
        {
            "Severity": "LOW",
            "InstalledVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2"
        },
        {
            "Severity": "HIGH",
            "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2016-2781"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to create the following JSON-file:

```
[
    {
        "Severity": "LOW",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2",
        "FixedVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2.1",
        "VulnerabilityID": ""
    },
    {
        "Severity": "LOW",
        "InstalledVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2",
        "FixedVersion": "",
        "VulnerabilityID": ""
    },
    {
        "Severity": "HIGH",
        "InstalledVersion": "",
        "FixedVersion": "",
        "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2016-2781"
    }
]
```

I have tried iterating over the first JSON-file, but when I do so in the following way, I get random parsing errors (with the real JSON-file I am working with). So I think there is something off about the piping that I am doing.

```
jq -c '.Results[]' my.json | while read i; do
    echo $i;
done
```

In the JSON-file I am working with **jq -c '.Results[]'** works perfectly, but when I do **jq** operations on the resulting **$i** while iterating, I suddently get several parsing errors.

Is there better way to iterate over key-value-pairs in a JSON-file? Ofcause I could just install Python/R and do the typical drill, but I would really like for this to work in a shell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more variation

```bash
jq '[
    .Results[]
    | .FixedVersion //= ""
    | .VulnerabilityID //= ""
    | .InstalledVersion //= ""
]' file.json
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the cleanest solution, but it also keeps all variables that are not among "FixedVersion", "VulnerabilityID" and "Installedversion". I guess I can just select them in another jq :)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What have I and the other solutions not addressed about your stated requirements?

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt To also reduce the objects to those three fields try `jq '.Results | map({FixedVersion, VulnerabilityID, InstalledVersion} | .[] //= "")' file.json`.

Comment: @glennjackman Let's say that the input JSON-file had 50 keys, where not all are unique, and I only wanted to extract three keys. Using the suggested code one gets all keys in the output.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `+` to add two objects together by combining their fields; if both objects have the same one the value of the right hand one is used. So if you make your existing object the RHS:

```bash
 jq '[ .Results[] | {Severity:"", InstalledVersion:"", FixedVersion:"", VulnerabilityID:""} + . ]' input.json   
[
  {
    "Severity": "LOW",
    "InstalledVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2",
    "FixedVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2.1",
    "VulnerabilityID": ""
  },
  {
    "Severity": "LOW",
    "InstalledVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2",
    "FixedVersion": "",
    "VulnerabilityID": ""
  },
  {
    "Severity": "HIGH",
    "InstalledVersion": "",
    "FixedVersion": "",
    "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2016-2781"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of adding the fallbacks to a empty string:

```
[ .Results[] | . + { VulnerabilityID: (.VulnerabilityID // ""), FixedVersion: (.FixedVersion // ""), InstalledVersion: (.InstalledVersion // "") } ]
```

```json
[
  {
    "Severity": "LOW",
    "InstalledVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2",
    "FixedVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2.1",
    "VulnerabilityID": ""
  },
  {
    "Severity": "LOW",
    "InstalledVersion": "1.21.1ubuntu2",
    "VulnerabilityID": "",
    "FixedVersion": ""
  },
  {
    "Severity": "HIGH",
    "VulnerabilityID": "CVE-2016-2781",
    "FixedVersion": "",
    "InstalledVersion": ""
  }
]
```

#### [Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PA8xGQgIglS)

Answer (score 1):

A more generic approach :

```
jq '.Results |
    (map(keys)|add|unique|map({key:.,value:""})|from_entries) as $default |
    map($default + .)
   ' input.json
```

Explanations :

```
1) map(keys)|add|unique
   gets all the keys. If it's a subset you are interested, you can substitute it with :
   ["FixedVersion", "VulnerabilityID", "InstalledVersion"]
2) map({key:.,value:""})|from_entries) as $default
   constructs a default object with all (or selected) keys.
3) $default + .
   adds a key from default object if the key does not exist.
```

Comment: Awesome with a generic solution also. Would you be up for explaining the different parts of the query?